# ID from a URL that does not include ?=id

Tags: php

I'm currently making a website (with PHP and a database) and there something I'm wondering about.

Can you get an ID from a URL like this for example `egh95.com/u1` or `egh95.com/t52-it-s-a-new-day`?
Like I only want the int to be my ID. I tried to use `$_Server["REQUEST_URI"]` and strip all the characters and symbols from the URL, but the int I got, didn't work to get the information out of the database.

I know how to use `$_GET["id"]` to get the int from the URL (that's the only thing that works atm), but I actually don't want the URL to be `?=id1` or something like that.

Comment: You need to store à mapping between each id and its corresponding url segment, parse the request and try to find à matchning id and if located return the correct page

Comment: What do you mean get an int? You'd like to get u1 from egh95.com/u1 or just 1?

Comment: Just the 1 from egh95.com/u1 so that it can be my ID to get the information out of the database

Answer (score 0):

I'd just use a basic regex, if that's the case.

```
$url = 'egh95.com/u1';
preg_match('/^.*\/u(?P<data>.*)/', $string, $matches);
echo $matches['data'];
```

$matches['data'] contains the number after u, in this case 1. [Here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) are some docs for regex in PHP, if you're interested.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Apache, you can use ModRewrite to implement user-friendly URLs. It is easy way to achieve what you wrote about with small amount of work. Then write in `.htaccess` file following lines: (Assuming you want to process the id in `index.php` file)

```
Options FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule "^u(.*)$" "index.php?id=$1"
```

Comment: With the line  `RewriteRule ^u([0-9]+) u.php?id=$1 [NC,L]` it actually worked